# Retrieve a specific websocket connection

Tags: go, websocket

I am trying to send a message to a WebSocket by referencing it's specific connection, which I maintain in a map of `map[*websocket.Conn]bool`. I do *not* want to broadcast the message using a channel but instead want to send a direct message to a specific connection.

```
(godebug) p clients.conn
map[*websocket.Conn]bool{(*websocket.Conn)(0xc420126000):true, (*websocket.Conn)(0xc4200f86c0):true}
```

I have opted out of Gorilla for now and am using the `x/net/websocket` sub-repository.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I know you dropped Gorilla, but the Gorilla chat example is a great place to start.  With the Gorilla example, you can send to a single connection using `client.send <- message`.  In other words, send to one connection instead of loop over all connections.

Comment: Noted. I shall take a look at that example!